# Create template email with Automator

Tags: automator

Is it possible to create a automator shortcut of some kind that creates a new mail in Apple Mail with a specific email address in TO and a specific text in Subject?

Answer (score 0):

If the **Recipient** and the **Subject** of the new Email is going to be the same every time, you can edit the `toRecipient` and the `emailSubject` of this following **AppleScript** code then add a `Run AppleScript` command to a **new Automator Quick Action** and paste the code into the `Run AppleScript` command

```
property toRecipient : "John_Doe@gmail.com"
property emailSubject : "Insert Email Subject Here"
property emailContent : "Insert Email Content Here"

sendNewEmail()


to sendNewEmail()
    tell application "Mail"
        activate
        set newEmail to (make new outgoing message)
        set content of newEmail to emailContent
        set subject of newEmail to emailSubject
        tell newEmail
            make new to recipient with properties {address:toRecipient}
        end tell
    end tell
end sendNewEmail
```

[image]

After you name and save your new **Automator Quick Action**, all you need to do is assign it a new **Keyboard Shortcut** in **System Preferences**.

[image]